# ACF - How to insert a repeater row inside a group?

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am programmatically creating a post using wp_insert_post(). My post is being created successfully. I am also using Advanced Custom Fields. I am trying to insert content into the new post's repeater fields using the update_field() and update_sub_field() commands, but to no avail. In some cases I can insert the data, but then retrieving it using `get_field('field_name', $post_id)` returns empty.

Am I missing something or am I inserting the data into the wrong place?

My field groups can be seen [here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IoREW.png)

**I have tried:**

```
update_field( 'system_preset_1_inverter_group', 'test_data' , $new_quote_id );
update_sub_field( array('system_preset_1_inverter_group', 1, 'inverter'), 'test_data' , $new_quote_id );
update_sub_field( array('system_preset_1', 1, 'inverter_group', 1, 'inverter'), 'test_data' , $new_quote_id );
```

Note: doing this works fine, but it is not a part of a group or a repeater field:

```
update_field( 'preset_or_custom' , $systems_preset , $new_quote_id );
```

I have also tried this:

```
// Inverters
$preset_1_flag = 1;
  foreach ( $system_preset_1_inverters as $insert_inverter_1 ) {
    update_field( 'system_preset_1_inverter_group_' . $preset_1_flag . '_inverter' , $system_preset_1_inverter_brand . ' ' . $insert_inverter_1, $new_quote_id );
    $preset_1_flag++;
  }
```

I am happy to expand on this with any further necessary code.

## The Code

```
  // 1) Savings TAB
  $savings_1 = 'Yes';
  $savings_2 = 'Quarterly';
  $savings_3 = 333;
  $savings_4 = 'select';
  $savings_5 = $wud_system_size;
  $savings_6 = 35;
  $savings_7 = 0.8;
  $savings_8 = 0.38;
  $savings_9 = 0.12;
  $savings_10 = $data['fields'][128]['value'];
  $savings_11 = $data['fields'][129]['value'];


  // 2) Systems TAB
  $systems_preset = 'Preset';
  $systems_size = $wud_system_size;

  $default_inverters = get_field('inverters', 'options');
  $default_brands = $default_inverters['default_inverter_brands'];

  // This function returns an array of inverters.
  $system_preset_1_inverters = \Roots\Sage\CPT_Solar\solar_quote_choose_string_inverter( 1, $systems_size );
  $system_preset_1_inverter_brand = $default_brands['brand_1'];
  $system_preset_1_panels = $default_panels;
  $system_preset_1_no_panels = ceil($systems_size * 1000 / $default_panel_wattage[1]);


  $system_preset_2_inverters = \Roots\Sage\CPT_Solar\solar_quote_choose_string_inverter( 2, $systems_size );
  $system_preset_2_inverter_brand = $default_brands['brand_2'];
  $system_preset_2_panels = $default_panels;
  $system_preset_2_no_panels = ceil($systems_size * 1000 / $default_panel_wattage[1]);


  $system_preset_3_inverters = '0.27'; // TBA
  $system_preset_3_inverter_brand = $default_brands['brand_3'];
  $system_preset_3_panels = $default_panels;
  $system_preset_3_no_panels = ceil($systems_size * 1000 / $default_panel_wattage[1]);


  // Insert the post into the database
  $new_quote_id = wp_insert_post( array(
      "post_title" => 'QID-temp',
      "post_content" => '',
      "post_type" => 'solar_quote',
      "post_status" => "publish"
  ));

  $the_quote['post_title'] = 'QID-' . $new_quote_id;
  $the_quote['ID'] = $new_quote_id;

  // Update post title.
  wp_update_post( $the_quote );

  // =========================
  // Update the post with all relevant details below.
  // =========================


  // THESE ALL SEEM TO WORK FINE.
  // 1) Update Savings Tab
  update_field( 'calculate_savings_system_size' , $savings_1 , $new_quote_id );
  update_field( 'electricity_bill_frequency' , $savings_2 , $new_quote_id );
  update_field( 'electricity_bill_amount' , $savings_3 , $new_quote_id );
  update_field( 'system_size_recommendation' , $savings_4 , $new_quote_id );
  update_field( 'selected_system_size' , $savings_5 , $new_quote_id );
  update_field( 'percentage_time_home' , $savings_6 , $new_quote_id );
  update_field( 'daily_supply_charge' , $savings_7 , $new_quote_id );
  update_field( 'rate_of_power' , $savings_8 , $new_quote_id );
  update_field( 'feed_in_tariff' , $savings_9 , $new_quote_id );
  update_field( 'savings_from' , $savings_10 , $new_quote_id );
  update_field( 'savings_to' , $savings_11 , $new_quote_id );


  // THIS ISN'T WORKING
  // Inverters
  $preset_1_flag = 1;
  foreach ( $system_preset_1_inverters as $insert_inverter_1 ) {
    update_field( 'system_preset_1_inverter_group_' . $preset_1_flag . '_inverter' , $system_preset_1_inverter_brand . ' ' . $insert_inverter_1, $new_quote_id );

    $preset_1_flag++;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I case you can see your ACF data in the backend.

When creating the new post and using update field, you need to use the field key instead of field name -

This is because that it does not have a referance in the database with that name yet -

so in some cases, it will save it to the post in the backend, but only if you press "update" or "publish" will the ACF be readable in the code.

Find the field key using the inspector in your browser on a posts edit page - and use that in "update_field" instead.

It will be something like field_xxxxxxxxx - and you need to use the entire thing -

If this does not help, then you might have the wrong data format for inserting sub fields. which i believe should be in form of an array.

Comment: Would this be using the id="acf-field_5a0920031ad52-field_5a138f6da9073-0-field_5a0920031ad53" or the name="acf[field_5a0920031ad52][field_5a138f6da9073][0][field_5a0920031ad53]" ?

Comment: **This is how the 3 rows appear (they are select fields):** `Row 1 ID: acf-field_5a0920031ad52-field_5a138f6da9073-0-field_5a0920031ad53
Row 2 ID: acf-field_5a0920031ad52-field_5a138f6da9073-5a4ed406a621d-field_5a0920031ad53
Row 3 ID: acf-field_5a0920031ad52-field_5a138f6da9073-5a4ed4c9a621e-field_5a0920031ad53



Row 1 Name: acf[field_5a0920031ad52][field_5a138f6da9073][0][field_5a0920031ad53]
Row 2 Name: acf[field_5a0920031ad52][field_5a138f6da9073][5a4ed406a621d][field_5a0920031ad53]
Row 3 Name: acf[field_5a0920031ad52][field_5a138f6da9073][5a4ed4c9a621e][field_5a0920031ad53]`

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention you @Stender

Answer (score 0):

For now, I've managed a workaround using update_post_meta(). It's not ideal, but it works by manually mapping the fields to the field keys.

```
  update_post_meta( $new_quote_id, '_system_preset_1', 'field_5a0920031ad52');
  update_post_meta( $new_quote_id, 'system_preset_1', '' );

  update_post_meta( $new_quote_id, '_system_preset_1_inverter_group', 'field_5a138f6da9073');
  update_post_meta( $new_quote_id, 'system_preset_1_inverter_group', count($system_preset_1_inverters));


  $preset_1_flag = 0;
  foreach ( $system_preset_1_inverters as $insert_inverter_1 ) {

    update_post_meta( $new_quote_id, 'system_preset_1_inverter_group_' . $preset_1_flag . '_inverter', $system_preset_1_inverter_brand . ' ' . $insert_inverter_1);
    update_post_meta( $new_quote_id, '_system_preset_1_inverter_group_' . $preset_1_flag . '_inverter', 'field_5a0920031ad53');

    $preset_1_flag++;
  }
```